# Terminal functiong the terminal to type make hello it

Tags: terminal, powershell-2.0

please I'm new in coding and I'm currently coding C language..and I'm using Windows 10 ..so my question is when I try using the terminal to type make hello it will say not in Cmdlet, function ... check path ?... what can I do to please .. I'm using powershell

Comment: Figure out where you have "make" and make it available in the PATH environment variable. Does it work from a "cmd" window?

Comment: I am a little confused about what tools you are using. The tags mention C# and Powershell, but the question mentions C. Do you know which you are using? `not a cmdlet` means that you have entered something that isn't a valid command in the terminal. If you have an `exe` file you want to run, make sure the terminal is scoped to the folder containing your `exe`. You can do this with the `cd` command (Change Directory). Ex: `cd C:/users/me/desktop/`. If you just want it to print `hello`, enter `echo hello`

Comment: I'm using powershell

Comment: @Aliah have you looked through a quick tutorial such as this one: https://therenegadecoder.com/code/hello-world-in-powershell/? It explains how to use PS and create a small script to use/re-use later.